# Nothing shows up when trying to print Christmas Tree

Tags: java

The task is to create a Christmas tree from stars. The length of the base is specified by the user in the file. The Christmas tree should be displayed in a different file. Of course, recursively.The problem is that nothing in the file shows up. What did I do wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("In0103.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    int maxWidth = in.nextInt();
    int initialWidth = 1;
    int initialLevel = 1;
    int maxLevel = (maxWidth + 1) / 2;
    int freeSpace = maxLevel - 1;

    printChristmasTree(initialWidth, initialLevel, maxLevel, freeSpace);
}

static void printChristmasTree(int width, int level, int maxLevel, int freeSpace) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter save = new PrintWriter("Out0103.txt");
    if (level < maxLevel) {
        save.println(Stream.generate(() - > " ").limit(freeSpace).collect(Collectors.joining()));
        save.println(Stream.generate(() - > "*").limit(width).collect(Collectors.joining()));
        save.println();
        printChristmasTree(width = width + 2, ++level, maxLevel, --freeSpace);
    } else {
        save.println(Stream.generate(() - > " ").limit(freeSpace).collect(Collectors.joining()));
        save.println(Stream.generate(() - > "*").limit(width).collect(Collectors.joining()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that every recursive call you open a new `PrintWriter` to the file. Not positive, but I would not be surprised if that was the cause of your issue, as I believe if the file exists then it is truncated to 0 bytes.

Comment: Also think you might need to manually flush the stream by calling `flush()`. Some streams will auto-flush occasionally. Not sure about PrintWriter though

Answer (score 0):

You should close the printWriter to persist the data in the file.

Try this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("In0103.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        int maxWidth = in.nextInt();
        int initialWidth = 1;
        int initialLevel = 1;
        int maxLevel = (maxWidth + 1) / 2;
        int freeSpace = maxLevel - 1;

        printChristmasTree(initialWidth, initialLevel, maxLevel, freeSpace, null);
    }

    static void printChristmasTree(int width, int level, int maxLevel, int freeSpace, PrintWriter save) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if(save == null) {
            save = new PrintWriter("Out0103.txt");
        }
        if (level < maxLevel) {
            save.print(Stream.generate(() -> " ").limit(freeSpace).collect(Collectors.joining()));
            save.println(Stream.generate(() -> "*").limit(width).collect(Collectors.joining()));
            printChristmasTree(width = width + 2, ++level, maxLevel, --freeSpace, save);
        } else {
            save.print(Stream.generate(() -> " ").limit(freeSpace).collect(Collectors.joining()));
            save.println(Stream.generate(() -> "*").limit(width).collect(Collectors.joining()));            
            save.close();
        }
              
    }
```

Comment: This works, but the tree looks like a right triangle. I don't know if I can put a picture here, so I'm sending a link
https://i.imgur.com/q0xQrq4.png it should look like this
https://i.imgur.com/eyuccNn.png

Comment: What to do to display the Christmas tree correctly?

Comment: @RafalMasny you **may** need to ask another question since that's a different issue.

Comment: @RafałMasny I edited the code to solve your problem. You was doing it right, but in the string that contains the blank spaces you should call ```save.print()``` instead ```save.println()```. You was putting the blank spaces in another line.